# Python: Appending using index referencing of a list in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use the index of a list (`codes`) to append the corresponding letter from the dictionary (`keys`) to a new list (`decodedlist`) using a `for` loop.

After using trial and error, I realised I need to use a `i-1` in `decodedlist.append(keys[codes[i-1]])` to get the result I want (`abcde`).

I can't figure out why and I am curious if there are alternative/ more efficient ways of coding this.

```
import re

samplecode='''
1asd 2asd as3d 4 asd5asd'''

codes = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}',samplecode)  
codes = list(map(int,codes))

keys = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c',4:'d',5:'e',6:'f',7:'g',8:'h',9:'i',10:'j'}

decodedlist=[]  
    for i in codes:  
    decodedlist.append(keys[codes[i-1]])

decodedstr=''.join(decodedlist)  
print(decodedstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Python are 0 indexed so the first item is at index 0. Your dictionary is 1 indexed with the first item at 1.